# How to recover deleted photo album saved on internal memory - Note 3

Tags: backup, gallery, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a Samsung Note 3 and I accidentally deleted an entire photo album from my phones gallery. I didn't enable my device to sync with Gmail. I didn't manually backup any of the data. The images were saved on my phone, not on the SD card. Is there any way for me to recover this deleted photo album? I Google'd and came across SDrescan but that won't work since the images were not initially saved on my SD card.

Comment: You can connect your phone to your computer using USB mode instead of MTP mode and use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover media files

Answer (score 0):

Considering you phone is always writing some kind of data to your internal storage, it's going to be a very difficult to recover them - at least not all anyway.

Unless something like PhotoRec can do it (as mentioned in the comments), I'd say they are gone for good.

An alternative, and probably a very expensive one, is to take it to someone who specialises in data recovery. Search for 'mobile phone data recovery' on Google and see what appears in your area. It may mean sending your phone away.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is painful. Happened with me once.

You will have to root your phone in order to get the data back, but it usually only works if the root has been done before the incident. There are several softwares for different OS which enables us to do deep scan and fetch the data files from the phone which had been lost (You should be able to open the phone as a **Mass Storage** after that which makes it easier to scan for the software). One of the best software is **Recuva**.  Read [this](http://www.androidpit.com/how-to-recover-lost-data) for more information.

Android storage works like a computer storage - every deleted file is still stored in a temporary storage until it is overwritten, but it isn't visible to us. It can be accessed by rooting your device + using certain softwares, but rooting should be avoided as much as possible. So if you think that these pictures are worth that, then check it out. Otherwise take precautions in future.

You can [Install this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baloota.dumpster) in your phone. This application works as Recycle Bin and stores every deleted file in it and can be restored easily.

Comment: Android doesn't have a "recycle bin". If you delete something it's deleted. The reason you can recover things is a function of how the filesystem performs the delete. It doesn't (generally) overwrite the data you've deleted, and instead simply marks the space as "available" and removes the pointer to the file. Thus, until the data is overwritten, it may be possible to recover it.